# Instagram {"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Your facebook account's off-Facebook activty in turned off."}

Tags: instagram

When I try to connect my Facebook page to an Instagram account this message appears:

```json
{
    "error_type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 400, 
    "error_message": "Your facebook account's off-Facebook activty in turned off."
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you may have done this? https://gadgets.ndtv.com/social-networking/features/off-facebook-activity-tracking-turn-off-how-to-tutorial-steps-app-website-2354708

Either way, not a programming question as far as I can see.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you may have disabled 'off-Facebook Activity'. While this feature allows you to control what website data is tracked by Facebook,  it can also prevent other platforms you're integrated with from accessing the data needed to connect to your accounts.

To get rid of the error:

Log in to your account on the Facebook site and then click on the down arrow from the top right of the screen.

Select Settings & privacy and click on the Settings option. Now, click on Your Facebook Information from the left column and then on the Off-Facebook activity option.

You can also directly visit the Off-Facebook activity page after logging in to your Facebook account.

Click More options from the right sidebar and then select Manage Future Activity. You'll now see a pop-up screen from where you need to click on the Manage Future Activity button.

Now,click on the button next to the Future Off-Facebook Activity option to turn on the ‘off-Facebook activity'.

Alternatively you can click into Activity You've Turned Off to see if a specific platform you want to give access to,  is listed.